Expo AV manual quality selection
I want to give user a way to select quality of video , I have a m3u8 file. Is there any way to do so in Expo AV package. I think it is possible to select a video quality manually according to the react-native-video documentation using the selectedVideoTrack Prop, but I didn't found any expo av alternative. Am I missing anything?
I have tried manually changing the url by parsing the m3u8 file but it feels a bit janky. And I dont know how to use audio url and video url together.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
